# double click and select the path(including '/') in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm using Terminal.app on Mac OS10.6.3, with gnu screen and zsh.

What I want to do is, see `pwd`(or an URL) in Terminal.app and double click on it, and select the whole path, to copy and paste after that.

But what I get now is a single directory name, because '/' is not treated as a word.
I found that iTerm has a setting to change it(iTerm -> Preferences -> Mouse -> Characters considered part of a word), but is there any way to do this on my environment?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Given the age of this question, you have probable found the answer elsewhere already, but if not, here's how to do it in "newer" versions of Terminal *(Leopard 10.5 and Snow Leopard 10.6)*...

> **<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> double-click**

See also [here](https://superuser.com/questions/45024/mac-os-x-terminal-app-how-to-select-pathnames/45081#45081).

Just to summarize:

- to select a path or a URL: <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-`double-click`

  > **<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>⇧</kbd> double-click**
- to select non-contiguous selections: <kbd>command</kbd>-`click-and-drag`

  > **<kbd>⌘</kbd> click-and-drag**
- to select block regions: <kbd>alt</kbd>-`click-and-drag`

  > **<kbd>⌥</kbd> click-and-drag**

Hope this helps.

Loads more useful keyboard shortcuts in this [article](http://ss64.com/osx/syntax-keyboard.html).

Comment: One more, Double-click and drag will do word by word selection instead of click and drag's letter by letter.

Comment: Ubuntu has double click do this by default.  Another reason we pay extra money for something extra worse.

Comment: They could have made a selection separator list in preferences. But yeah I can feel arrogance of Apple Cook. May be I'll switch to putty in my MacBook if that's what they want.